# Selenium Bot Bypass

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, undetected-chromedriver, bypass

I wrote a python program to automate timebucks.com with help of selenium the terms of service of the websites states that if I make more than same accounts all my accounts will be banned and the same happened all my accounts were banned after a month so I want to figure out what I can include in my code that they cant detect that I am running multiple accounts on the same device with multiple chrome profiles.

I tried running all the chrome tabs in visible mode and not in headless mode
and I also included these lines I got from an article

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", \['enable-automation'\])\`
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () =\> undefined})")
```

but it didn't help me

Comment: Flags alone won't do any help. You could specify in your code to use a specific Chrome profile. I am assuming that you are not doing it now as it is not seen from the code you have provided. You could have at another thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77914990/selenium-stuck-in-cloudflares-checking-if-the-site-connection-is-secure. The examples there are for C# but the general idea, apart from specific NuGet packages should be the same.

Comment: i am using different chrome profiles with threading its not the problem that is not the full code the problem is that all the profiles uses same ip adress i want different ip either with help of proxy or something elseaddress in