# Selenium: Stuck in Cloudflares "Checking if the site connection is secure"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare

So since this week my selenium test fails because the cloudflare does not redirect me to the page i want to open.

Im seeing this:
[image: Cloudflare stucked]

Im executing my selenium tests in incognito and these are the arguments im using:

```
ChromeOptions options = new();
options.AddArguments("--incognito");
options.AddArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArguments("--lang=en");
options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
```

When i open the website in normal mode or incognito mode, it works with no problems.

Only when it opens with selenium, i get stucked there.

I tried to use `options.AddArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");` as mentioned in other answers, but this doesnt solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: evading bot-detection is a moving target, but you need much more than just setting some flags in your browser options.  (they can, for instance, check for certain javascript hooks or global variables)  If the site checks for bots and prevents them from browsing the site, you should consider being a good internet citizen and using their approved APIs or methods, or ask permission to run your bot.

Comment: Its not a bot. Its just a test where i simply want to open a random block (random number between 1 and 50000) and compare values. Nothing more. Simple UI comparisson test. To make sure that the values are the same on a other website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @browsemator in the comment you just experienced Cloudflare's bot detection and I don't think that is is possible to easily avoid it. However there are at least two options you could try.

### Undetected Chrome Driver

I assume you are using C# so you could use either [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.UndetectedChromeDriver) or [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver) NuGet package to setup your driver. If you would use the first one, then the setup would look something like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Create(driverExecutablePath: "path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
```

There is an option (I don't remember with which package of these two) to install the chromedriver automatically without you needing to handle this yourself, but I could only make that work for latest versions of chromedriver and those do not include the actual latest ones needed for latest chrome.

### Chrome Profile

You could use an existing Chrome profile. Your code would look something like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument($"--user-data-dir={userDataDir}");
options.AddArgument($"--profile-directory={profileDir}");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

For `userDataDir` and `profileDir` you would need to specify the path for your specific Chrome profile which you can find by typing `chrome://version` in your browser. For an example we would see in the "Profile Path" section this path:

```
C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Some Profile
```

With this example path the value for `userDataDir` would be `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` and for `profileDir` the value would be `Some Profile`.

This is how this approach would help:

1. Open Chrome in the specific profile that will be used for automated test
2. Navigate to the site manually
3. Close the window of that specific profile (all the windows)
4. Run the test

When you open the website manually, a cookie is created which Cloudflare checks to verify that it is not a bot user. The cookie remains during the automated test as you are using that same specific Chrome profile. Keep in mind, that this might periodically fail as the cookie might expire or Cloudflare will do some additional checks or something and you will need to repeat the manual opening of the website from time to time.

Comment: Im trying your second suggestion first as it looks simples. When i open chrome://version, do i use the "Profile Path" for both, userDataDir and profileDir? Or where does this one belong to?

Comment: that second method is pretty interesting... surprising that Cloudflare doesn't set that as a session cookie.

Comment: @MrBeardy for `userDataDir` you use the path to the "User Data" directory and for `profileDir` just the directory name. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, adding the user to chrome actually solved the problem for me